# How to add an unlimited number of class instances with user input in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to use

```
class reader
def __init__(self, name, booksread)
    self.name = name
    self.booksread = booksread
while True
    option = input("Choose an option: ")
    if option = 1:
        #What to put here?
```

I want to create an unlimited number of instances of the reader class, But I could only figure out how to do it a limited number of times by using variables for the class. I also need to call the info later (without losing it). Is it possible to do this with a class? Or would I be better off with a list, or dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

First: `if option == 1:` is always false in python 3, input only reads strings there.
Second: python [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) can be expanded until you run out of RAM.
So the solution would be to create a list in the surrounding code and call append on that every time you have a new item:

```
mylist = []
while True:
    mylist.append(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possibly to populate a data structure (such as a list or dict) with instances of a class, given your code example you could put the instances into a list:

```
class reader
def __init__(self, name, booksread)
    self.name = name
    self.booksread = booksread

list = []
while True:
    option = input("Choose an option: ")
    if option == 1:
        list.append(reader(name,booksread))
```

Note: I don't know how you are obtaining the values for 'name' or 'booksread', so their values in the list.append() line are just placeholders

To access the instances in that list, you can then iterate over it, or access elements by their indexes, e.g.

```
# access each element of the list and print the name
for reader in list:
    print(reader.name)

#print the name of the first element of the list
print(list[0].name)
```

Comment: Awesome! This was a big help.